# Underscore JS, Grouping by an array Attribute.

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to use Javascript to group an array by one of it's attributes.

Essentially I have a list of e-mail templates, and I'm trying to group them by the category that they are in so that I can make a collapsible accordion with it later.

I think I might have the syntax of underscore JS wrong, or I'm addressing my array incorrectly. Currently I am calling groupby using the following command:

```
console.log(_.groupBy(result, 'im_category'));
```

but my array looks like the 'im_category' property is hidden under the attributes function. I'm not sure how to get there.

I've attached my console.log of what the array looks like and what happens when I run that command. (I get three different objects when I should get 2 if it's working correctly. )

[image: console.log of me running the commands.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `im_category` is a property of the `attributes` object in your `businessEntity` - `_.groupBy` is looking for properties of `businessEntity`. You need to create a function as `iteratee`:

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(result, function (item) {
  return item.attributes.im_category;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jwnzh8w0/